# Copying Theme from Firefox to Waterfox

Tags: firefox-extensions, waterfox

How do I copy this theme from Firefox 56 to Waterfox 56? It's apparently not as simple as copy paste in the prefs.js file as I was hoping. Within Waterfox there is no image, only color changes. Is the image embedded internally into Firefox now? Can I save it locally and instead of the URL, make it a local hard drive inquiry?
Thanks in advance.

```
{\"id\":\"161687\",\"name\":\"Toothless How to Train Your Dragon\",\"headerURL\":\"http://getpersonas-cdn.mozilla.net/static/8/7/161687/Toothless.jpg?1270059927\",\"footerURL\":\"http://getpersonas-cdn.mozilla.net/static/8/7/161687/Toothlessfooter.jpg?1270059927\",\"textcolor\":\"#ffffff\",\"accentcolor\":\"#212d62\",\"iconURL\":\"http://getpersonas-cdn.mozilla.net/static/8/7/161687/preview_small.jpg?1270059927\",\"previewURL\":\"http://getpersonas-cdn.mozilla.net/static/8/7/161687/preview.jpg?1270059927\",\"author\":\"Mydnite\",\"updateURL\":\"https://www.getpersonas.com/en-US/update_check/161687\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy. Instead:

1. https://www.waterfox.net/addons/
2. Thunderbird …
3. Themes
4. seek *toothless*

Amongst the results, an original:

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/firefox/addon/toothless-how-to-train-your/

- 2012-11-24
- not versioned.

More recent versions 1.0 (2019-01-26) and 2.0 (2019-05-13) are at https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/toothless-how-to-train-your/ and please note:

- these two release dates may be unrelated to changes by the developer of the add-on (I suspect that Mozilla ran a batch process, in May, that updated various themes)
- if you use a status bar extension such as [Status-4-Eva](https://github.com/SparkyBluefang/S4E) with Waterfox Classic, the more modern themes that are served at AMO may be **less** effective than the originals that were weeded from AMO.

The 2012 version:

[image: Screenshot of the 2012 theme]

2019 version 1.0:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Graham for the response. Although those themes are similar in design, none match the one that I have attached to Firefox.